# Query to get items based on difference of min,max in group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following entries:

```
 ID    Title       Year
 1     Avatar      2009
 2     Avatar      2020
 3     Hello       2014
 4     Hello       2013
 5     New         2017
```

Here is how I would get each title with all its years:

```
SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Year) FROM table
```

And it would give me:

```
Title        Years
Avatar       2009,2020
Hello        2013,2014
New          2017
```

How would I do a query to get all results where the min(Year) is more than 5 years away from the max(Year). The correct result would then be:

```
Title       Years       > 5 Year Diff
Avatar      2009,2020   YES
Hello       2013,2014   NO
New         2017        NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is wrong.  It should be:

```
SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Year)
FROM table
GROUP BY title;
```

To implement what you want is simply a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Year),
       (CASE WHEN MAX(YEAR) - MIN(YEAR) > 5 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) as flag
FROM table
GROUP BY title;
```

Quite often, such a flag would be encoded as "1" for true and "0" for false.  In this case, you would just use the boolean expression for the flag:

```
SELECT title, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Year),
       (MAX(YEAR) - MIN(YEAR) > 5) as flag
FROM table
GROUP BY title;
```

Note that this usage is a MySQL extension (but it happens to be one that I like).

Comment: Thanks -- the second approach is very elegant and easy to read as well. Thanks for pointing out the error/typo in my query as well.